# Changing Android Toolbar DrawerArrowToggle color

Tags: android, menuitem, material-design, android-toolbar, drawertoggle

I am using Appcompat 7 in my project for Toolbar with navigation toggle. Everything works except the requirement to change the color of **DrawerArrowToggle** icon dynamically when each activity or fragment changes.

My `styles.xml` file code is as follows:

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#F2F2F2</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">false</item>
        <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
```

In the above styles file I have used **DrawerArrowToggle** color as **White**, but my requirement is to change into some other color in runtime. I have not posted any code since I am completely stuck and no where I could find even a single piece of code for my requirement.

Comment: Just use (in kotlin)
`
toolbar.navigationIcon?.apply {
      if (this is DrawerArrowDrawable) 
            color = /*yourColor*/
}
`
I know it is a late answer but just in case someone needs it in future.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this could work, I haven't tested myself.

First obtain [view reference](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/bb963f9b8f40beb954a0) of the navigation icon:

```
 public static View getToolbarNavigationIcon(Toolbar toolbar){
        //check if contentDescription previously was set
        boolean hadContentDescription = TextUtils.isEmpty(toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription());
        String contentDescription = !hadContentDescription ? toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription() : "navigationIcon";
        toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(contentDescription);
        ArrayList<View> potentialViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        //find the view based on it's content description, set programatically or with android:contentDescription
        toolbar.findViewsWithText(potentialViews,contentDescription, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
        //Nav icon is always instantiated at this point because calling setNavigationContentDescription ensures its existence 
        View navIcon = null;
        if(potentialViews.size() > 0){
            navIcon = potentialViews.get(0); //navigation icon is ImageButton
        }
         //Clear content description if not previously present
        if(hadContentDescription)
            toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(null);
        return navIcon;
     }
```

Once you get the view reference apply `ColorFilter` to the drawable in this case the ActionBarDrawerToggle icon:

```
View navigationIcon = getToolbarNavigationIcon(mToolbar);
Drawable navDrawable = navigationIcon.getDrawable();
if(navDrawable != null){
   navDrawable.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}
```

Comment: Clearing the Content Description is a bad idea from an accessibility stand point. Perhaps instead you could use the view's tag to store something to indicate it has already been changed?

Comment: Indeed. Clearing contentDescription in this snippet will happen if it was not set previously.